# Prove the jump times of a poisson process in a given interval are uniformly distributed

Tags: poisson-process

Can someone provide a reference for this fact on the internet?

While I know this fact is proved in many text books, but I cannot find a proof of this fact very easily on the internet

Comment: If you're lucky your post may become your reference (sorry :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~uriy/Papers/encyc57.pdf - page 5 in this does that do it?